# Solution for the recurrence algorithm

Tags: algorithm

How is T(n) = 4T(n/2 + 2) + n solved ?

I found a solution in a website:
https://ita.skanev.com/04/04/03.html

I don't understand it.

Is T(n) = 4T(n/2 + 2) + n equivalent with T(n) = 4T(n/2) + (n + 2) ?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is just Case 1 in the Master Theorem. You can read the theorem here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms).

Basically, in your problem, a = 4, b = 2, and c = 1. So, we have log_b(a) = 2 > c. Therefore T(n) = Theta(n^2).